Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to class in Anylogic
I am quite new to java in Anylogic and therefore feel this is probably a quick fix.
I have defined a class type called OperationResults:
    public class OperationResults {
    private final double multiplicationResult;
    private final double additionResult;
    private final double subtractionResult;

    public OperationResults(double mulRes, double addRes, double subRes) {
        this.multiplicationResult = mulRes;
        this.additionResult = addRes;
        this.subtractionResult = subRes;
    }
}

The function in my simulation is called 'callAPI' that simply sends two double values ('a' and 'b') to my python API code. Both sets of codes are as follows. My 'callAPI' function:
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:5000/operations");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        String jsonInputString = "{\"a\": " + a + ", \"b\": " + b + "}";
        try (OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream()) {
            byte[] input = jsonInputString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            os.write(input, 0, input.length);
        }

        try (InputStream is = conn.getInputStream(); Scanner scanner = new Scanner(is)) {
            String jsonResponse = scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").next();
            JSONObject response = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
            double multiplicationResult = response.getDouble("multiplicationResult");
            double additionResult = response.getDouble("additionResult");
            double subtractionResult = response.getDouble("subtractionResult");
            return new OperationResults(multiplicationResult, additionResult, subtractionResult);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return new OperationResults(-1, -1, -1); // Error handling
    }

My API python code:

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/operations', methods=['POST'])
def operations():
    data = request.get_json(force=True)
    a = data['a']
    b = data['b']
    result_multiply = a * b
    result_addition = a + b
    result_subtraction = a - b
    return jsonify({
        'multiplicationResult': result_multiply,
        'additionResult': result_addition,
        'subtractionResult': result_subtraction
    })

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

My button in my simulation that executes the function is as follows:
for (Learner agent : learners) {
    double a = agent.edu1Resources;
    double b = agent.edu3Cost;

    // API call
    OperationResults results = callAPI(a, b);

    // Update agent attributes or handle results
    agent.multiplicationResult = results.multiplicationResult;
    agent.additionResult = results.additionResult;
    agent.subtractionResult = results.subtractionResult;

    // Print results for each agent
    traceln("Agent ID " + agent.getIndex() + ": edu1Resources * edu3Cost = " + results.multiplicationResult + 
            ", edu1Resources + edu3Cost = " + results.additionResult + 
            ", edu1Resources - edu3Cost = " + results.subtractionResult);
}

The two errors that I am getting state that "Type mismatch: cannot convert from class 'OperationResults' to double" in the function's code and "Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to class 'OperationResults'" in the button's code.
I really hope there is a simple explanation for my errors as everything else seems to be okay. Would much appreciate the help.
Here is my stack trace:

    Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to Main.OperationResults
    at _2024_03_28.Main.executeShapeControlAction(Main.java:651)
    at _2024_03_28.Main$6.action(Main.java:695)
    at com.anylogic.engine.presentation.ShapeControl.executeAction(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.presentation.ShapeButton.executeUserAction(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.gui.ExperimentHost.executeUserAction(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.internal.webserver.f.onAction(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.executor.basic.rest.BasicAnimationSessionController.lambda$null$3(BasicAnimationSessionController.java:71)
    at com.anylogic.engine.internal.webserver.e.acceptToAnimationSvgSession(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.executor.basic.rest.BasicAnimationSessionController.lambda$startController$4(BasicAnimationSessionController.java:71)
    at spark.ResponseTransformerRouteImpl$1.handle(ResponseTransformerRouteImpl.java:47)
    at spark.http.matching.Routes.execute(Routes.java:61)
    at spark.http.matching.MatcherFilter.doFilter(MatcherFilter.java:134)
    at com.anylogic.engine.internal.webserver.config.ALServerFactory$1.lambda$0(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.QoSFilter.doFilter(QoSFilter.java:202)
    at com.anylogic.engine.internal.webserver.config.ALServerFactory$1.doHandle(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1598)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:487)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:732)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:479)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:315)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:409)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:883)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1034)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)


Could you include the full Java method (specifically, include the function signature of callAPI()), and the stack trace (showing which methods were called)?

Hi @Kaan. My Java method is as follows:
    // method body
}```

I have also added my stack trace above.

Thanks. It looks like there is more code to share: what is executeShapeControlAction()?

I have no idea. I am guessing it is a function built into AnyLogic, the simulation software I am currently using. The code that I have given so far, is all the code that I added to the simulation.

I found the solution. In my function callAPI written in AnyLogic, I changed the expected output type from 'double' to 'Other' and then stated OperationResults. This was done under the 'Returns value' option. Instead of expecting to give a function output of double, the function output is in the class type OperationResults that I created in my class code on the main page.
